# How do I know that a view is on fast-view state, programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

We develop an Eclipse RCP Application that is built on Eclipse 3.8.  We're trying to build it on Eclipse 4.8 and some of our code was broken, given the removal of some classes.

On Eclipse 3.8, we know a view is on fast-view state when this line returns `null`:

```
( (PartSite)viewPart.getSite() ).getPane().getContainer();
```

But both `PartSite` and the method `getContainer()` are not available anymore on Eclipse 4.8.

How can we check if a view is on fast-view state?

Comment: Fast views don't existing any more

Comment: Maybe not under that name, but the idea still exist (or maybe I'm using the wrong name).  I'm talking about the views that are minimized, appear as icons on the borders of your workbench, and can be shown temporarily  "floating" over the workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no fast views in Eclipse 4, just minimized parts.

You will need to use some of the e4 APIs to determine if the part or its container is minimized. Something like:

```java
EPartService partService = getSite().getService(EPartService.class);

MUIElement part = partService.findPart(getSite().getId());

MElementContainer<?> parent = part.getParent();

if (parent == null) {
   part = part.getCurSharedRef();

   parent = part.getParent();
}

boolean minimized = isMinimized(part) || isMinimized(parent);


private boolean isMinimized(MUIElement element) {
   List<String> tags = element.getTags();
   return tags.contains(IPresentationEngine.MINIMIZED) && !tags.contains(IPresentationEngine.ACTIVE);
}
```

You can track the changes in minimized tags like this:

```java
IEventBroker broker = getSite().getService(IEventBroker.class);

broker.subscribe(UIEvents.ApplicationElement.TOPIC_TAGS, event -> {
   Object element = event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.ELEMENT);
   Object newValue = event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.NEW_VALUE);
   Object oldValue = event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.OLD_VALUE);

   if (IPresentationEngine.MINIMIZED.equals(newValue))
     System.out.println("min added " + element);
   if (IPresentationEngine.MINIMIZED.equals(oldValue))
     System.out.println("min removed " + element);
 });
```

Comment: Nice try, but it didn't work.  The list returned by `element.getTags()` never contains `IPresentationEngine.MINIMIZED`.

Comment: Well this is what the code in `EPartService.isPartVisible` uses to check for minimized. Try just calling `EPartService.isPartVisible`

Comment: In some cases you need to look at the shared ref - updated the answer. Also note that it is normally the parent rather than the view that has the minimized tag.

Comment: Way to go!  I only had to change the `isMinimized` method to remove the second condition, because we need it to be true even if the view is being shown.  By the way, I discovered another way to do this, by checking if `activePage.getPartState( iViewReference ) == IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED`.  Thank you very much, Greg.